# Не достает и недостает

Tags: орфография

Можно заметить, что две эти формы не всегда различаются авторами, причем весьма уважаемыми:

1) "Я замечаю, брат, что ты приуныл; говори прямо: чего тебе не достаёт? [А. С. Пушкин. Арап Петра Великого (1828)]. (В других изданиях встречается слитное написание).

Вспоминать о том, что так хотелось бы забыть навсегда, у меня не достает ни духу, ни сил. [Ф. И. Буслаев. Мои воспоминания (1897)]

Видимо, у нас сейчас просто не достаёт воображения, чтобы понять, на какие подвиги были готовы герои Великой фальсификации ради того, чтобы надёжнее обмануть потомков. [А. А. Зализняк. Лингвистика по А. Т. Фоменко // «Вопросы языкознания», 2000]

2) Ступил конь в воду, шагнул три раза и ушёл в воду по шею, а дальше нога и дна не достаёт (Гаршин).

Так надо различать НЕДО и НЕ+ДО? И возможно ли в этой теме авторское решение?

Comment: Vera, у меня есть ссылки,но пользоваться этим словарём я не хочу, потому что он какой-то "левый", он выдаёт не парадигму данной словоформы, а невесть что. Например, ввела предикатив НЕВАЖНО, он выдал неважный во всех падежах, или вот какой-то глагол "достаивать", достаиваю, достаиваешь,а в русском языке их нет (даже Ворд подчёркивает).Вот и безличный глагол недостаёт в полной парадигме личных форм,но с не слитно . http://starling.rinet.ru/cgi-bin/morph.cgi?word=[njedostavat%27]    
 http://starling.rinet.ru/cgi-bin/morph.cgi?word=[njedostat%27

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Недостаёт - безличный глагол, но происходит от глагола с двойным значением - личным и безличным. Др.-русское достати ("заполучить" и безличн. "выпадать, приходиться") восходит к праславянскому "хватать, заполучить" (до + стать).

От "достать" образовалось "достаток" (то, что досталось) - богатство, довольство. (Суф. производное от страдат. прич. (достатъ) глагола достати «нажить, приобрести, получить» < «добыть, достать, взять» (ср. хватит и хватать). Школьный этимологический словарь русского языка. Происхождение слов. — М.: Дрофа Н. М. Шанский, Т. А. Боброва 2004)
Недостаток - отсутствие достатка и мало достатка.

Достаток - достаточный - удовлетворяющий чему-либо.

Достаточный - достаточно - первонач. "обеспеченно" - значительно, довольно - хватит.

Недостаточно - не хватает, мало.

Мы наблюдаем, как расходятся значения слов. Мы воспринимаем безличный глагол недостаёт уже не от глагола достаёт - достать - хватать, заполучить, а от существ. достаток, а "достаёт"(=достаточно), как всегда в таких случаях, остаётся в народной среде - в диалектах и просторечии (там сильна традиция исконных значений). Появляется правило:

Различается раздельное написание не доставать в значении «не дотягиваться» и слитное написание недоставать в значении «быть в недостаточном количестве», «быть нужным», например:
1) не достает рукой до форточки;

2) в кассе недостает двух рублей; недостает терпения; только 
этого недоставало.

Формируется новая приставка "недо" со значением недостаточности действия и качества, но глагола "недостаёт" это не касается, здесь действует правило "без НЕ в этом значении не употребляется" (не/доста/ёт).

Приставку недо-, придающую глаголу значение неполноты, недостаточности действия мы видим в словах, где приставка  антонимична приставке пере-: недовыполнить – перевыполнить, недосолить – пересолить), недобрать тетрадей, недоварить картофель, недовернуть гайку, недовесить масла, недогрузить вагон, недооценить свои возможности, недополучить часть товара, недоедать, недосыпать, недосмотреть, недослышать, недоучесть.

Comment: У Розенталя:http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/38.htm

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, правило мне понятно, но не очень понятна его история и практика применения. Когда именно приставка НЕДО стала осознаваться как противоположная приставке ПЕРЕ? И почему так много ошибок в текстах, такое впечатление, что на правило мало кто обращает внимание. Что касается классиков, то это понятно, но почему наши современные авторы предпочитают раздельное написание для всех случаев? И что делать с классиками, взять хотя бы пушкинского "Арапа Петра Великого"?

Comment: Знаете, в наше время отсутствия корректоров при издательствах так часты опечатки, что грамотность по текстам проверять нельзя, а уж в Нацкорпусе тем более никто при наборе не проверяет. В моём печатном тексте Пушкина  "недостаёт" - слитно, вот в этом тоже:
http://rvb.ru/pushkin/01text/06prose/01prose/0856.htm  А вот когда именно приставка "недо" появилась - сказать сложно, вероятно, уже в 19 веке. Современные авторы и на другие орфограммы внимания мало обращают, а эта вызывает сложности (в разговорном варианте вполне произносится "У нас в доме всего достаёт") - пишут, как считают нужным.

Comment: По Зализняку проверила парадигму - все слова слитно, правда, в одном случае написано:недоставать(более верно "не доставать"), потому что начальной формы у неизменяемого безличного глагола "недостаёт" нет, так что инфинитив только раздельно, а недостаёт-застывшая форма.

Comment: "Человеку может просто недоставать силы воли". Так нельзя сказать? Или вот еще пример: "После смерти академика Лихачева  стране остро будет его недоставать".

Comment: Ну вот поэтому Зализняк эту фразу в скобках и убрал из последующих работ, чтоб не прицепились. Мы ж понимаем, что будущее время образуется с помощью инфинитива и в будущем времени словоформа будет писаться так, как в настоящем - слитно. Исключений в русском языке много, это одно из них. (Как под мышкой - "мышки" нет, но пишется раздельно, как с сущ., потому что остались падежные формы). И никто не цепляется.

Comment: Знаете, я так и не поняла, какова парадигма глагола "недоставать". Вроде бы говорится, что она неполная, а в некоторых словарях приводятся все возможные формы. А у Вас есть ссылка на "Грамматический словарь Зализняка онлайн"?

Answer (score 4):

> *И возможно ли в этой теме авторское
> решение?*

От Розенталя и Добромыслова ("Трудные вопросы грамматики и правописания". М., 1958):

> …Что касается безличного глагола
> ***недостаёт***, то он пишется слитно, так
> как без отрицания ***не*** этот глагол в
> значении "достаточно" не
> употребляется. Нельзя сказать: *"Мне
> достаёт хлеба".* Глагол ***достаёт*** без ***не***
> употребляется только в значении
> определённого движения
> ("дотягивается") или в значении
> "добывает", "находит" *(Он где-то
> достаёт эти редкие книги).*

Comment: А какова история этой орфограммы? Классики, по-моему, нисколько не старались различать эти формы (очень много примеров в Нацкорпусе с раздельным написанием). Когда их стали различать и регулировать? И Зализняк почему пишет раздельно (опечатка или намеренное решение)?

Comment: И странное объяснение у Розенталя. Почему он не выделяет приставку НЕДО со значением неполноты, недостаточности действия или признака?

Comment:  Vera: "Когда их стали различать и регулировать?"=== Как минимум, со времён Грота. Уже у него было: "Слитно пишут также: нельзя, недоставать (как глагол безличный)".

Comment:  Vera: "И Зализняк почему пишет раздельно (опечатка или намеренное решение)?"=== Конечно, опечатка.